# PHP preg_match '£'

Tags: php

Bit surprised but the following...

```
static public function VerifyAndFormatStreet(&$addrStr, $mustExist)
{
    if( $addrStr !== NULL )
    {       
        $addrStr = trim($addrStr);

        // SNIP

        if( preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9 -.,]/', $addrStr) )
        {
            printf("\t### FAIL: BAD CHARS\n");
            throw new JEH_IllegalParameterException("Address contains illegal characters");
        }

        $addrStr = ucwords(strtolower($addrStr));
        printf("PASS STRING IS NOW $addrStr\n");
    }
    else if($mustExist)
        throw new JEH_IllegalParameterException("Address must not be empty");
}
```

The following call then fails to find an invalid character in `$street2`...

```
$pass = FALSE;
try { JEH_Address::Create("12 Somestreet", "Junk£", "Frlington", "", "Portsmouth", "Hampshire", "UK", "PO1 1XX"); }
catch(JEH_IllegalParameterException $e) { $pass = TRUE; }
if( !$pass ) die("Was able to detect bad char!!!\n");
else         printf("PASS\n");
```

But if I change the `preg_match()` function to the following in the `Create()` function...
(Put the space at the end of the set)

```
if( preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9-., ]/', $addrStr) )
```

The function works.

Any idea why moving the space in the character-match set works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`A-Za-z0-9 -.,` includes four ranges

1. A to Z
2. a to z
3. 0 to 9
4. [space] to ,

if you move the space to the end of the array, then that last one becomes

```
0-9-.
```

Which isn't a valid range, and so the dash is treated as dash, rather than as part of a range.

Comment: This is why I tend to always put `-` at the end of my character groupings if I want a literal `-` matched, as that will never produce a character range.

Comment: @ajp15243 - I tend to escape anything that could be misinterpreted

Comment: @andrewsi Agreed, but sometimes escaping characters can reduce readability, so I'll try to keep readability first before escaping, if it's possible and not too much of a pain.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the dash, or else you'll create a range just like with `A-Z`. So you created a range from space to `.` to match against. (You'll have to look it up in a character table to see what those are.) Try:

```
/[^A-Za-z0-9\-., ]/
```